# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

i am trying to make an app that requires to loop through an array of JSON objects. For this i first create an ArrayList and then convert it to an Array and loop through it, however i get the following error:

```
Day::drawEvents |
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length = 16;
regionStart = -2;
regionLength = 1
```

The error doesn't even show up on the logcat as an error it only displays as popup message on the device.

The code that i suspect causes the error:

```
List<JSONObject> appointments = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonAppointments);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");

    JSONArray jsonData = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.length(); i++) {
        appointments.add(jsonData.getJSONObject(i));
    }

List<JSONObject> appointments = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

...adding items to the ArrayList...

JSONObject[] appointmentsArray = new JSONObject[appointments.size()];

appointments.toArray(appointmentsArray);

int len = appointments.size();

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    start = appointmentsArray[i].getInt("start") * 1000L;
    ...processing the array content...
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line exactly caused the exception?

Comment: I am not sure since the logcat doesn't report it, it only shows as a blue popup on my deivce. But this is the only part of executed code that uses indexes to find values in an array

Comment: This is StringIndexOutOfBoundsException so this is about indexing strings. This probably some other part of the code or internal working of something you used. An array would throw a more generic IndexOutOfBoundsException, I think.

Comment: i've updated my answer with some more code that also uses some indexing, furthermore i dont have anything in my program that uses string indexes, just adding and creating strings thats it.

Comment: @SjoerdvdBelt so maybe show part when you create strings.

Comment: I don't think that creating regular string variables would cause any error, besides that has nothing to do with indexing so it wouldnt cause an indexerror i think.

Comment: Do you know JSON that it gets stuck on?

Comment: Post your json response too